# Replace the alternate occurances of a substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My input strings are like:

1. `A or B OR C or D OR E or F`
2. `A OR B OR C OR D OR E OR F`

Expected Output: `'A or B' OR 'C or D' OR 'E or F'`

```
outputString = '''' + REPLACE(@inputValue COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, ' OR ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, ''' OR ''') + ''''
```

I tried using SQL Replace function and the above statement works properly for the first string and I get the desired output but for the second string since we have all the ORs in the uppercase it fails and returns `'A' OR 'B' OR 'C' OR 'D' OR 'E' OR 'F'`

I'm using SSMS 15.0.

How can I solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to swing this without regex support, which sadly SQL Server does not gave.  Would there always be _four_ letters separated by `OR` ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, there could be more letters also. I'll edit it.

Comment: Per this article https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-the-sql-replace-function/ we can write the pattern in SQL Server Replace function. I was thinking of checking the index and replace the Even ORs but don't know how to implement on SQL.

Comment: Do you need it to be case sensitive?

Comment: Yes, it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a UDF.

The function splits a string on a pattern as a resultset.
*(similar as the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function, but with a pattern)*

The `FOR XML` trick is then used to construct a string from the splitted parts, and to add the quotes.

> ```
> DECLARE @vchNewValue VARCHAR(100), @result VARCHAR(100);
> SET @vchNewValue = 'A OR B or C OR D or E OR F';
>
> SET @result = LTRIM(RTRIM((
>        SELECT
>          CASE WHEN match = 1
>          THEN ' '+quotename(ltrim(rtrim(replace(value,' OR ',' or ') )),'''')+' ' 
>          ELSE UPPER(value)
>          END
>        FROM dbo.fnPattern_Split(' '+@vchNewValue+' ', ' % OR % ') AS spl
>        ORDER BY ordinal
>        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)')
>     ));
>
> SELECT @result AS result;
> ```

| result |
| --- |
| 'A or B' OR 'C or D' OR 'E or F' |

Test *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=884209c18ede955beb098a8d418ab174)*

**The UDF**

Uses PATINDEX to find each next start position of the given pattern in the string.

Then finds the nearest end position where the pattern is still valid.
So it's kinda like a lazy search in regex.

The positions are then used to insert the parts into the returned table.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnPattern_Split
> (
>   @str     VARCHAR(MAX),
>   @pattern VARCHAR(100)
> )
> RETURNS @tbl TABLE (
>  ordinal INT,
>  value VARCHAR(MAX),
>  match BIT
> )
> WITH SCHEMABINDING
> AS
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX)
>         , @splitvalue NVARCHAR(MAX)
>         , @startpos INT = 0
>         , @endpos INT = 0
>         , @ordinal INT = 0
>         , @foundend BIT = 0
>         , @patminlen INT = ISNULL(NULLIF(LEN(REPLACE(@pattern,'%','')),0),1);
>   WHILE (LEN(@str) > 0)
>   BEGIN
>     
>     SET @startpos = ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%'+@pattern+'%', @str),0), LEN(@str)+1);
>     
>     IF @startpos < LEN(@str)
>     BEGIN
>         SET @foundend = 0;
>         SET @endpos = @startpos+@patminlen-1;
>         
>         WHILE @endpos < LEN(@str) AND @foundend = 0
>         BEGIN
>           IF SUBSTRING(@str, @startpos, 1+@endpos-@startpos) LIKE @pattern
>             SET @foundend = 1;
>           ELSE
>             SET @endpos += 1;
>         END
>     END
>     ELSE SET @endpos = LEN(@str);
>     
>     IF @startpos > 1
>     BEGIN
>       SET @ordinal += 1;
>       SET @value = LEFT(@str, @startpos-1);
>       INSERT INTO @tbl (ordinal, value, match)
>                 VALUES (@ordinal, @value, 0);
>     END
>     
>     IF @endpos >= @startpos
>     BEGIN
>       SET @ordinal += 1;
>       SET @splitvalue = SUBSTRING(@str, @startpos, 1+@endpos-@startpos);
>       INSERT INTO @tbl (ordinal, value, match)
>                 VALUES (@ordinal, @splitvalue, 1);
>     END
>     
>     SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str, @endpos+1, LEN(@str));
>   END;
>   RETURN;
> END;
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, for case 2 where input is: A OR B OR C OR D OR E OR F I get the following output: 'A OR B' OR 'C OR D' OR 'E OR F'. However, the expected is: 'A or B' OR 'C or D' OR 'E or F'. Please let me know if that can also be handled.

Comment: @user1547554 Fixed. Little tweaks in the `CASE WHEN`.

Comment: Please explain this as well, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution that stuffs the quotes.

The recursive CTE loops through the string while finding the start positions of the ' or ' patterns.

Since ' or ' has 4 characters, having a start position means you also have the end position.

The`STUFF` function can insert characters in a string on positions.

So the positions are used to stuff the quotes where needed.
Which is every even occurence *(modulus 2 of lvl is 0)*.

> ```
> declare @input varchar(100)
>       , @result varchar(100);
> set @input = 'A OR B or C OR D or E OR F';
> set @result = @input;
>
> with rcte as (
>   select 1 as lvl
>   , charindex(' or ', @input) as pos
>   , len(@input) as max_pos
>   union all
>   select lvl+1
>   , isnull(nullif(charindex(' or ', @input, pos+4), 0), max_pos) 
>   , max_pos
>   from rcte
>   where pos < max_pos
> ) 
> select @result = stuff(stuff(@result,pos+4,0,''''),pos,0,'''')
> from rcte
> where lvl%2 = 0 and pos+4 < max_pos
> order by lvl desc;
>
> SET @result = ''''+@result+'''';
> SET @result = REPLACE(REPLACE(@result,' OR ',' or '),''' or ''',''' OR ''');
>
> select @result as result;
> ```

| result |
| --- |
| 'A or B' OR 'C or D' OR 'E or F' |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e8ed5ab7c897202602a59b03e323ef99)*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have accepted the other solution as an answer but this one also works perfectly. Could you please just explain me a bit? Thanks a lot. If possible then please add some comments.

Comment: Well, creating that UDF was harder.  And this method depends on more assumptions.  I tried to explain this one in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solution comes with a high cost on server load since while is used.

```
declare @input varchar(100) 
set @input = 'A or B or C or D or E or F or G or'

declare @inc int = 1, @end int = 1
,@final varchar(100) = '', @part varchar(100)
,@nextposition varchar(100), @or varchar(10)= ''
,@last varchar(10), @ifendsOR varchar(10)

select @nextposition = case when @input like '%or' then substring(@input,1,len(@input)-2) else @input end
select @ifendsOR = case when @input  like '%or' then ' or' else '' end
select @last = ltrim(rtrim(right(@nextposition,2)))

while  @end <> 0
begin 
select @part = substring(@nextposition,1,charindex('or',@nextposition)-2)
select @nextposition = replace(@nextposition,concat(@part,' or '),'')
set @end = charindex('or',@nextposition)
select @or = case when @inc%2 = 0 then ' OR ' else ' or ' end
set @inc = @inc+1
set @final = concat(@final,@part,@or)
end
select @ifendsOR = case when @inc%2 = 0 then upper(@ifendsOR) else @ifendsOR end
select concat(@final,@last,@ifendsOR)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, for case 2 where input is: A OR B OR C OR D OR E OR F
I get the following output:  'A OR B' OR 'C OR D' OR 'E OR F'. However, the expected is: 'A or B' OR 'C or D' OR 'E or F'.  Please let me know if that can also be handled. Else, I'll too ahead with your current solution.

Comment: Yes, both can cases be handled, 
the query breaks the input string based on the 'OR' / 'or' position and then adds OR and or based on occurrence. So this should work.