# Comma-delimited string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using T-SQL, I have a comma delimited string like this

```
'Value1,Value2,"Value3,Value4,Value5",Value6'
```

and I want to put it into an array like this:

```
Array[0] = 'Value1'
Array[1] = 'Value2'
Array[2] = 'Value3,Value4,Value5'
Array[3] = 'Value6'
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as an "array" in tsql - so the premise of your question is not valid. But splitting strings is THE MOST COMMON question on SO - a simple search will find many examples. But since you reference "array", it may be that your coding environment has better features to accomplish this. A better question might be why you store CSV data in strings - you pay a constant and significant price for improper normalization.

Comment: Note that T-SQL's in built string splitting features don't support quoted strings. I would suggest you do this in a different language.

Comment: If the other values would also be double-quoted then you could simply unnest them as a JSON array via OPENJSON. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71213419/4003419)

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  It's just that the comma delimited string is created from other system and I just pull down.  SQL server pulls it from a website on the internet and that is the way that they built their string.  One way to initiate the transfer is from a website, then SQL server pulls this from the source.  Then the result will be sent back to the client to be parsed. I created a javascript to parse this kind of string but the way I did it was to go through each and every character from left to right.

Comment: Now, I need to automate a couple of things and pull the comma delimited string from the source.  No access to the javascript I created since there is no client involved.  I tried to use split_string but that wont help.

If I remember it right, there was a process where you can import a csv file into a table in SQ: server.  On that process, you can specify the delimiter ( the character that separates fields) and the character delimiter (the double " that implies that it is a string).  I really cannot remember how to do it, so much more in script.  Do you guys know this import process? Thanks!

Comment: sorry if I use array as an example.  A table will suffice as long as it parses the string correctly.

Comment: _SQL server pulls it from a website on the internet and that is the way that they built their string._ Why is SQL Server itself pulling data from the internet? Are you using the `sp_OA*` OLE Automation Stored Procedures that are intentionally disabled by default because they present huge security and stability (threading and resource leak) problems for SQL Server?

Comment: I'm aware of that, as long as you know the risk and what to look for.  I believe I'm good to go.

Comment: @jong - What version of SQL Server are you using, please?

Comment: Clearly you are not aware of what to look for, as you don't appear to have a very good understanding of SQL Server. I *strongly* recommend you use Powershell, C# or Python to retrieve data from the internet, rather than using old, unstable and difficult-to-debug procedures

Comment: That's a bit degrading @Charlieface.  This isn't a difficult task in SQL Server even all the way back to SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @jong - Asking again, what version of SQL Server are you using, please?

Comment: @JeffModen I was specifically referring to the use of `sp_OA` procedures, and how they have a number of major pitfalls (as I'm sure you know), and require careful use of error handling, timeouts and monitoring for leaks. I'm not saying they will never have uses, I'm saying that OP clearly doesn't have a good enough grasp of SQL Server if they are asking about arrays and how to split strings, at least not on the level I would say they could use the aforementioned procedures. I think it's simply inadvisable for most people to use them, and that other procedural languages are far better placed.

Comment: I do apologize to OP for coming across as cutting, I just want to bring across the point that T-SQL is *not* a generalized scripting language, and should not be used as such. It has poor error handling, poor (and essentially hacky) web access, and poor thread management. I'm just advising that OP find another method to access the web.

Comment: @Charlieface - I don't see where the OP ever mentioned sp_OA.  I do see where someone else asked if the OP was using sp_OA but blew it off because it doesn't matter to me how the OP is getting the data at this point.  As for the use of sp_OA, I agree that you have to watch the "gazintas" but MS does claim to have repaired the memory leaks that it supposedly used to have.  I also agree that SQL Server isn't a general scripting language but, if you know no other and your back is up against the wall and you've gotta get it done NOW, it's not difficult to do this in SQL until you can do elsewhere.

Comment: And, it can be done without cursors or loops.  I just need to know what version of SQL the OP is using so I can demo the appropriate level of code.

Comment: Heh... I just got the warning about avoiding extended discussions in comments and it asked me if I'd like to move it to chat.  What we should do is move it to a forum that allows extended discussions. :D  @jong - You should ask this question on SQLServerCentral.com. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted method.
But it can transform the string in the format of a JSON array.
Then it'll be easier to use [JSON functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server) on it.

The example uses a UDF `fnPattern_Split` that accepts a pattern to unnest the string.
The source code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70802887/4003419)

> ```
> declare @str varchar(max), @js varchar(max);
> set @str ='Value1,Value2,"Value3,Value4,Value5",Value6';
>
> ;with cte1 as (
> select *
> from dbo.fnPattern_Split(@str,'"%"') ps
> ) 
> , cte2 as (
>   select ordinal as ord1, 0 as ord2, value 
>   from cte1 
>   where match = 1
>   union all
>   select c.ordinal, ps.ordinal, quotename(ps.value,'"') as value 
>   from cte1 c
>   cross apply fnPattern_Split(c.value,',') ps
>   where c.match = 0 and ps.match = 0
> ) 
> select @js = '['+string_agg(value, ',')
>                  within group (order by ord1, ord2)+']'
> from cte2;
>
> print(@js);
>
> select *
> from OPENJSON(@js) js;
> ```

| key | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Value1 | 1 |
| 1 | Value2 | 1 |
| 2 | Value3,Value4,Value5 | 1 |
| 3 | Value6 | 1 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0ae475e15b03a4c894b00b1895b4a9e6)*